# Construction of parent abstract class

Tags: java, oop, model-view-controller, abstract-class

Java newbie here.
I got two classes (let´s call them A and B) and some of the methods (e.g. `doSomething(...)`) they contain are pretty much similar in the sense that they actually share same code. I decided to make my code more effective and use some sort of parent abstract class C from which the classes A, B will inherit.

Here is my issue. Method **doSomething** in class A has following signature:

`doSomething(VievForA view, ...)`

while same method **doSomething** in class B has signature like:

`doSomething(VievForB view, ...)`

As you can see the method doSomething uses different type of first parameter so I don´t know how to solve this in the abstract class.

**What´s the correct way to construct the class C and what should the method doSomething look like?** 
I hopefully explained my situation well, otherwise I can add some more pseudocode.

Answer (score 3):

You can also have a base view class which will get inherited by ViewA and ViewB and use ViewBase as the parameter for doSomething.

Comment: This solution solve the doSomething signature issue on child classes A and B ( event if it needs an explicit cast on these ones ) but it needs something more to helps to avoid also to reuse common code on specific implementations

Answer (score 2):

You can structure your code using Java **generics** as follow:

```
// View Classes
//====    

/**
 * The generic view parent class
 */
public abstract class GenericView{
}

/**
 * The specific A view class
 */
public class ViewForA extends GenericView{
    //...
}

/**
 * The specific B view class
 */
public class ViewForB extends GenericView{
    //...
}

// View Handler Classes
//====

/**
 * The generic view handler
 * @param <T> The view object that extends from GeneriView
 */
public abstract class C<T extends GenericView>{

    private void doGenericSomething(GenericView t) {
        //Do something generic on all views
    }

    //Do something specific on specific view
    abstract void doSpecificSomething(T t);

    //Do all stuff
    protected void doSomething(T t){
        doGenericSomething(t);
        doSpecificSomething(t);
    }

}

/**
 * The specific A view handler
 */
public class A extends C<ViewForA>{

    @Override
    void doSpecificSomething(ViewForA view) {
        //Do your stuff with viewForA
    }
}

/**
 * The specific B view handler
 */
public class B extends C<ViewForB>{

    @Override
    void doSpecificSomething(ViewForB view) {
        //Do your stuff with viewForB
    }
}
```

This way you can insert your **common** code on `doGenericSomething(GenericView t)` body at C class and then let each specific view class such as A and B classes to implement the **specific** code on `doSpecificSomething(ViewForSpecific t)` where ViewForSpecific is a class that inherits from GenericView ( like ViewForA and ViewForB in the shared code ).

Comment: This is interesting! Can you elaborate a bit on the advantage of using this vs just using plain subclasses? You do have one additional class now. Is this worth the effort?

Comment: What do you mean specifically with "using plain subclasses"? And also what is the additional class added with this solution?

Comment: I mean A, B, C, C<T, are those not four?

Comment: Why you reported **C<T** as class? Probably you don't know Java generics. Check the generic syntax on Java documentation in order to get my example code correct meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a common inherited class as parameter for the method:

```java
doSomething(CommonViev view, ...)
{
   if (view instanceof VievForA)
   {
      VievForA vievForA = (VievForA)view;
      ...
   }
   else if (view instanceof VievForB)
   {
      VievForB vievForB = (VievForB)view;
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: `instanceof` is very useful in this case. Though I would try to use the "smallest common parent" as parameter type. `Object` is really the greatest common parent ever and then the method could be called with `doSomething("myString");` or `doSomething(1.23);`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would be better creating a common interface or abstract class. However, I wrote this only as example.

Comment: Should this method you shared be placed on C class? If yes, why C class that is intended to be generic should contain code for specific objects like vievForA and vievForB? Moreover doing this if you introduce another specific object like vievForC you should update the C class that should be instead used as library due its generic purpose and so should be changed the least possible. 
Also is a good practice to avoid to use instanceof when structuring code ( see this interesting article: https://www.armedia.com/blog/instanceof-avoid-in-code/ )

Comment: Thank you so much. It is very interesting and your example very illustrative.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are trying to maintain two classes A and B extending C,
then in C class, you make declaration like this.

```
doSomething(Object view, ...)
```

and In class A or class B, use like below

```
doSomething(Object view, ...){

VievForA(B) vievForA(B) = (VievForA(B)) view;     //basically typecast it as per child class

}
```

Comment: Sure, but I do not know which class called the method, so I will not be able to determine whether to cast to A or to B.

Comment: does the answer of @Roberto Fernández Iglesias answer this question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `doSomething()` has code that repeats itself you could implement common code in the `abstract` class `C` and use it in the implementation in `A` or `B`.

```
abstract class C {  
    protected Result doSomething(CommonStuff common){
        // doing common stuff and
        return result;  // returning the result
    }
} 


class A extends C { 
    public void doSomething(ViewForA view, ..){
         CommonStuff common = view.getStuff();
         Result result = this.doSomething(common);
         view.applyResult(result);
    }
}
```

But this is very ... abstract example. If your ViewForA and ViewForB have a common interface of any kind it would even be better to use this. Once I used the common Interface like this:

```
 abstract class C {

      abstract protected ViewInterface getView();

      protected void doSomething(){
           this.getView().doStuffWithView();
      }
 }


 class A extends C {
     private ViewForA myViewForA; 

     @Override
     protected ViewForA getView(){
          return this.myViewForA;
     }
  }
```

Then the abstract class can handle the `doSomething` by assuming that there will be any kind of common View instance to be used. And the classes A and B will automatically implement the common `doSomething` and you can use it like

```
A a = new A();
a.doSomething();
```